# How to convert excel data to json format in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, excel, mongodb

I am a beginner in nodejs, I was tasked to read a excel file and convert it into json format so that it can be stored into mongodb database.

**excel2.js file:**

```
const XlsxStreamReader = require("xlsx-stream-reader");
var fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./excelpush.json');
const db = require('./dbmanager.js');

var finalList = [];
var singlePerson = {};

class ExcelReader {

  readFile() {


    var workBookReader = new XlsxStreamReader();

    workBookReader.on('error', function (error) {
      throw (error);
    })

    workBookReader.on('worksheet', function (workSheetReader) {
      if (workSheetReader.id > 1) {

        workSheetReader.skip();
        return;
      }

      var isFirstLine = true;
      var headerIndex = [];

      workSheetReader.on('row', function (row) {


        if (isFirstLine) {

          headerIndex = row.values.slice(1);

        }

        else if (!isFirstLine) {

          let rowValues = row.values.slice(1);


          let valueIndex = 0;
          headerIndex.forEach(currentval => {

            singlePerson[currentval] = rowValues[valueIndex];
            valueIndex++;

          });
          finalList.push(singlePerson);
        }
        isFirstLine = false;

      });


      workSheetReader.on('end', function () {

      });

      workSheetReader.process()
    });
    workBookReader.on('end', function () {
      //console.log(finalList);

      console.log('finished!');
    });

    fs.createReadStream(config.filePath).pipe(workBookReader);

  }
}
excelReader = new ExcelReader();
excelReader.readFile();

db.connectDb();
db.insertDb(finalList);
```

**dbmanager.js file:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./db.json');

function connectDb() {
    mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${config.dbConfig.host}:${config.dbConfig.port}/${config.dbConfig.dbName}`);
    mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
        console.log('Connection has been made');
    }).on('error', function (error) {
        console.log('error is:' + error);
    })
}

function insertDb(list) {
    var myschema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false });
    var obj = mongoose.model('myschema', myschema, `${config.dbConfig.collectionName}`);
    var obj1 = new obj(list);
    obj1.save();
}


module.exports = {
    connectDb, insertDb
}
```

**db.json file:**

```
{
    "dbConfig": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": "27017",
        "dbName": "PRACTICE",
        "collectionName": "Excel"
    }
}
```

**excelpush.json file:**

```
{
    "filePath": "D:\\grv_tracx_updt (1).xlsx"
}
```

here **excel2.js** is taking excel file from **excel2.json** and reading it and storing as a array of objects in **finalList** variable.

In **dbmanager.js** file db connection and insertion code are written.

Here i am not able to store data in database, The code gets executed perfectly but data in not stored in mongodb database.

Note: excel file is large.

Comment: You've got a call `db.insertDb(finalList);` in excel2.js file, what isn't working with it?

Comment: i dont know how to provide the "finalList" variable which storing a array of objects to the dbmanager.js file so that it can store that excel data into database

Comment: ... but this doesn't answer Christopher's question at all. The way to do what you want seems to be `db.insertDb(finalList)`. You have that already. You are already passing the variable to that function. Hence the question : what's not working with it?

Comment: actually after passing the passing the variable and running the code i am not able to get data stored in database, the id is getting created in mongodb but data is not stored.